# Use first line words before colon to create column headers and remove from row for 1st and all remaining rows

Tags: python, pandas, split, row, multiple-columns

I have a csv file that I'm reading into a dataframe and would then like to take the first line and use each word before the colon as the column header and the strip the the remainder of the lines with the word before the colon.

Thank you in advance.

I have tried to re.sub, I have tried to split and join the rows, but without any luck.

Below is an example of the input and then output required:

```
Input
Date: 2019/03/20    ID: DD0011010   REF: 15987-AA
Date: 2019/03/21    ID: DD0011011   REF: 15987-AA
Date: 2019/03/22    ID: DD0011012   REF: 15687-AA
Date: 2019/03/23    ID: DD0011013   REF: 65987-AA
Date: 2019/03/24    ID: DD0011014   REF: 15990-AB

Expected Output
Date            ID              REF
2019/03/20      DD0011010       15987-AA
2019/03/21      DD0011011       15987-AA
2019/03/22      DD0011012       15687-AA
2019/03/23      DD0011013       65987-AA
2019/03/24      DD0011014       15990-AB
```

Comment: is the space between each column a fixed width?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently you just need some regex and `replace`

```
df.replace('[a-zA-Z0-9]*:\s+', '', regex=True)
```

Outputs

```
    col1        col2        col3
0   2019/03/20  DD0011010   15987-AA
1   2019/03/21  DD0011011   15987-AA
2   2019/03/22  DD0011012   15687-AA
3   2019/03/23  DD0011013   65987-AA
4   2019/03/24  DD0011014   15990-AB
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`df.applymap(lambda x: re.split(":", str(x))[1])`

Answer (score 0):

you can use a simple string splitter for this

```
def sep(t_string):
   return t_string.split(" ")
```

if `t_string = 'Date: 2019/03/20'`

```
sep(t_string)[0] = 'Date:'
```

and

```
sep(t_string)[1] == '2019/03/20'
```

and pass this function on the columns

```
d_table['column'] = [sep(t)[1] for t in d_table['column'].values]
```